# Simulate a swap / execute a swap on Raydium in Python

Tags: python, swap, raydium

I'm a newby on Solana and 0 understanding of RUST and Typescript. I'm looking for a solution to simulate swap on Raydium using Python, and then also the code to execute the swap. I've been trying to use solana-py and solders and all the examples I could find online but to no avail..   If anybody has such code, would you be so kind to share it here or on a repo on github? Eternally grateful! :D

Answer (score 0):

I went through this same struggle some time ago. Unfortunately the raydium swap SDK only supports Javascript but there is some way around it where you can do it all in python but it can become very tedious. I know that user [kokiez](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/6926/kokiez) had found a way to do it all in python and had it published on github, but since then I haven't been able to find it, you can perhaps try to message him and find out.

But anyways, what I did was I created all the raydium swap instructions, transactions and simulations using Javascript and then I used a websocket to send the parameters from python to the Javascript function. I know its a hassle buts thats currently the easiest way to do it in my opinion.

This is a good place to get started: https://github.com/precious-void/raydium-swap

And regarding the pool keys, I have found two ways to get it reliably:

1. FalconHit API ( costs 0.12 SOL per month): https://docs.valguibs.com/
2. Using typescript to get the pool keys almost instantly only requiring the input and output token addresses. I had used some inspiration from [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/faster-method-to-retrieve-pool-keys-raydium) post. Here is what the code somewhat looks like:

```
import { PublicKey, Commitment, Connection } from '@solana/web3.js'
import {
  LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4,
  Liquidity,
  LiquidityPoolKeysV4,
  MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3,
  Market,
  SPL_MINT_LAYOUT
} from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk'
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()

// const rpcCon = new Connection(process.env.WEB3_SOL_PROVIDER, { commitment: 'finalized' })

async function getPoolKeys(connection: Connection, base: PublicKey, quote: PublicKey, commitment: Commitment = 'finalized') {
    const rsp = await fetchMarketAccounts(connection, base, quote, commitment)
    const poolKeys = await formatAmmKeysById(rsp[0].id, connection)
    return poolKeys
}
  
async function formatAmmKeysById(id: string, connection: Connection): Promise<LiquidityPoolKeysV4> {
    const account = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey(id))
    if (account === null) throw Error(' get id info error ')
    const info = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(account.data)

    const marketId = info.marketId
    const marketAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(marketId)
    if (marketAccount === null) throw Error(' get market info error')
    const marketInfo = MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.decode(marketAccount.data)

    const lpMint = info.lpMint
    const lpMintAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(lpMint)
    if (lpMintAccount === null) throw Error(' get lp mint info error')
    const lpMintInfo = SPL_MINT_LAYOUT.decode(lpMintAccount.data)

    return {
        id: new PublicKey(id),
        baseMint: info.baseMint,
        quoteMint: info.quoteMint,
        lpMint: info.lpMint,
        baseDecimals: info.baseDecimal.toNumber(),
        quoteDecimals: info.quoteDecimal.toNumber(),
        lpDecimals: lpMintInfo.decimals,
        version: 4,
        programId: account.owner,
        authority: Liquidity.getAssociatedAuthority({ programId: account.owner }).publicKey,
        openOrders: info.openOrders,
        targetOrders: info.targetOrders,
        baseVault: info.baseVault,
        quoteVault: info.quoteVault,
        withdrawQueue: info.withdrawQueue,
        lpVault: info.lpVault,
        marketVersion: 3,
        marketProgramId: info.marketProgramId,
        marketId: info.marketId,
        marketAuthority: Market.getAssociatedAuthority({ programId: info.marketProgramId, marketId: info.marketId }).publicKey,
        marketBaseVault: marketInfo.baseVault,
        marketQuoteVault: marketInfo.quoteVault,
        marketBids: marketInfo.bids,
        marketAsks: marketInfo.asks,
        marketEventQueue: marketInfo.eventQueue,
        lookupTableAccount: PublicKey.default,
    }
    }

async function fetchMarketAccounts(connection: Connection, base: PublicKey, quote: PublicKey, commitment: Commitment = 'finalized') {
    const marketProgramId = new PublicKey('675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8')
    const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
        marketProgramId,
        {
        commitment,
        filters: [
            { dataSize: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.span },
            {
            memcmp: {
                offset: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.offsetOf("baseMint"),
                bytes: base.toBase58(),
            },
            },
            {
            memcmp: {
                offset: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.offsetOf("quoteMint"),
                bytes: quote.toBase58(),
            },
            },
        ],
        }
    );

    return accounts.map(({ pubkey, account }) => ({
        id: pubkey.toString(),
        ...LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(account.data),
      }));
    }

// getPoolKeys(rpcCon, new PublicKey('HZ4Qund5mESBvNngcGNGXrsjAUjvZGP8pNcVwANnQMRG'), new PublicKey('So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112'))

export default getPoolKeys
```

If you have any question, don't hesitate to ask.